# how to smooth ndvi curve in google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

[image]

how to smooth the ndvi curve,in which look like more continuous.
I had resample the curve in GEE,but it getting more bad

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of smoothing algorithms out there to use ([here](https://pasteur.epa.gov/uploads/A-kwhq/353/Time-Series%20Smoothing_rse.2016.pdf) is an article comparing some). The way I like to approach it is to get a list of dates in the image collection and map over that list while filtering/selecting the data that you need for the particular smoothing algorithm at that time. Here is a quick example using a linear regression moving window:

```
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2"),
    point = ee.Geometry.Point([-122.15815487909191, 37.81983948091395]);

var filteredIC = s2.filterBounds(point)
    .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2017-12-31')
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')

// function to add NDVI and time bands to image collection
var addDataBands = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi)
              .addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start').divide(1e18).rename('time'));
};

// Function to smooth time series
// stacks windows of linear regression results
// requires that a variable 'data' exists with NDVI and time bands
function smoother(t){
  // helper function to apply linear regression equation
  function applyFit(img){
      return img.select('time').multiply(fit.select('scale')).add(fit.select('offset'))
              .set('system:time_start',img.get('system:time_start')).rename('NDVI');
  }
  t = ee.Date(t);

  var window = data.filterDate(t.advance(-windowSize,'day'),t.advance(windowSize,'day'));

  var fit = window.select(['time','NDVI'])
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit());

  return window.map(applyFit).toList(5);
}

// function to reduce time stacked linear regression results
// requires that a variable 'fitIC' exists from the smooter function
function reduceFits(t){
  t = ee.Date(t);
  return fitIC.filterDate(t.advance(-windowSize,'day'),t.advance(windowSize,'day'))
              .mean().set('system:time_start',t.millis()).rename('NDVI');
}

var data = filteredIC.map(addDataBands);
print(data);

var dates = ee.List(data.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));

var windowSize = 30; //days on either side

var fitIC = ee.ImageCollection(dates.map(smoother).flatten());

var smoothed = ee.ImageCollection(dates.map(reduceFits));

// merge original and smoothed data into one image collection for plotting
var joined = ee.ImageCollection(smoothed.select(['NDVI'],['smoothed'])
                .merge(data.select(['NDVI'],['original'])));

var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: joined,
  region: point,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30
}).setOptions({title: 'NDVI over time'});

print(chart);

Map.addLayer(ee.Image(smoothed.sort('system:time_start',false).first()),{min:0,max:0.25,bands:['NDVI']},'Smoothed')
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(data.sort('system:time_start',false).first()),{min:0,max:0.25,bands:['NDVI']},'Original')
```

And the link to the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3e2e1c0dfdac28a9d4230ca32cb9d7f3

You can write your own custom functions using a similar approach to apply any smoothing algorithm you want.

I hope this helps!